# Why is ng-checked firing twice on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code, and it seems as though ng-checked is firing my simple alert method twice when the page loads.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app', ['common.ajax']);
  angular.module('common.ajax', []);

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('loginCtrl', controller);

  controller.$inject = ['$scope', 'ajaxFactory'];

  function controller($scope, ajaxFactory) {
    $scope.alertme = activate;

    function activate() {
      ajaxFactory.getData();
    }
  }

  angular
    .module('common.ajax')
    .factory('ajaxFactory', factory);

  factory.$inject = ['$http'];

  function factory($http) {
    var service = {
      getData: getData
    };

    return service;

    function getData() {
      alert("click me");
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.5.6" data-semver="1.5.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="loginCtrl">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="alertme()" ng-model="tester" />
</body>
```

I am just starting out on my Angular journey so any info on why this is happening would be great as I cannot seem to find anything in particular online.

Comment: It's firing twice because the digest loop will run at least twice. [See here](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/). As the answer below `ng-change` or `ng-click` is what you're looking for. But I would prefer the change handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you ment to use ng-click not ng-checked.

Look at the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

ngChecked is meant to be a boolean parameter, not a function.

> Sets the checked attribute on the element, if the expression inside ngChecked is truthy.

Answer (score 0):

ngChecked can take a function as a param so long that function return a truthy or falsy value like so:

```
const isGreaterThanOne = x => x > 1;

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="loginCtrl">  
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="isGreaterThanOne(2)" ng-model="tester" />
</body>
```