# ng-checked triggers its function more than once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

that's the code in the view :

```
 <input type="radio" name="tabset" id="tab2" aria-controls="rauchbier"
        ng-checked="switch_tabs()">
```

and that's the code in the controller

```
   $scope.switch_tabs = function(){
        console.log(notification_form_data);
        console.log($('#notification_form').serialize());
        if (notification_form_data != $('#notification_form').serialize() & notification_form_data!= undefined)
        { 
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'vs',
            template: 'unsaved data in actions',
            button: 'Done'

        });

    }
```

the alert and the console.log happens 100 times when the condition = true how to fire it only 1 time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is ng-checked firing twice on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948533/why-is-ng-checked-firing-twice-on-page-load)

Comment: What is the element that has the id `notification_form`? Why are you mixing jQuery with AngularJS? Whenever you do that, you are asking for trouble.

Comment: Whenever the `ng-checked` directive has an AngularJS expression that is a function, the function will be called multiple times each digest cycle until the returned value stabilizes. It will always be called at least twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Why is ng-checked firing twice on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948533/why-is-ng-checked-firing-twice-on-page-load)

ng-checked is meant to be a boolean. So it's meant to be like `ng-checked="checkbox_checked"` and that will check the checkbox when `checkbox_checked` is `true` for example.

You may want to use `ng-click` to fire your function once when the radio box is clicked.

Or if you want something to happen when a variable changes you can use `$scope.$watch`

```
$scope.$watch('notification_form_data', function() {
   if (notification_form_data != $('#notification_form').serialize() & notification_form_data!= undefined)
    { 
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: 'vs',
      template: 'unsaved data in actions',
      button: 'Done'
     };
})
```

Or you can add an `ng-model` and use `ng-change` which will call your function when the model changes. If you only want the alert to run when the radio box is checked, you can check if the variable used in your `ng-model` is true.

```
<input type="radio" name="tabset" id="tab2" aria-controls="rauchbier"
        ng-model="radio_checked" 
        ng-changed="switch_tabs()">
```

```
$scope.radio_checked = false
$scope.switch_tabs = function(){
        console.log(notification_form_data);
        console.log($('#notification_form').serialize());
        if (notification_form_data != $('#notification_form').serialize() && notification_form_data!= undefined && $scope.radio_checked)
        { 
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'vs',
            template: 'unsaved data in actions',
            button: 'Done'

        });

    }
```

Comment: how to fix that should i change ng-checked ?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked When you set ng-checked your saying you want the checkbox to be checked if the statement you pass it is truthy.

Comment: i want to fire alert when this condition is true what is the best soluotion ?

Comment: the user can click on already checked input that's not the best practise

Comment: i think ng-change is the best answer but it doesnt fire the function i dont know why

Comment: `ng-change` requires an `ng-model`. When the radio box is checked the ng-model will update. `ng-change` will call the function and then update the model. `ng-changed` will update the model and then call the function. If you only want the error to happen if they check the radio and not when they uncheck it you can just check if the model is true or false.